# Programatically can we use load in magento for array of products ids for getting product details

Tags: magento-1.9, product, programmatically

I am working on product collection. I am using

```
$product = $productModel->load(42);
```

I have array of products like :

```
$productArray = array('1','15','25','35','42');
```

I want to pass this array in load but it is not working and giving error. How we can multiple entity ids into load for getting all details once.

Comment: Hello!
Why don't you just use a foreach on $productArray and load each one of those ID's separately and get whatever information you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can get like that:

```
$productArray = array('1','15','25','35','42');
```

Try to use `addAttributeToSelect` in the query and check:

```
$product_ids = array('1','15','25','35','42');
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('barcode')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $product_ids));
```

Comment: But i am not getting details of product like Name , barcode etc after print_r($collection->getData()).

Comment: I want to load multiple products details once.

Comment: you have to load the product to get the data

Comment: Try :     $productArray = array('1','15','25','35','42');
      $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
       ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productArray));
    
           foreach($collection as $product) {
               $product = $product->load($product->getId());
     }

Comment: @Abdul i dont want to use load in foreach loop.

Comment: update the answer use addAttributeToSelect

Comment: @Mathew, need foreach loop or not?

Comment: @Quasar where i use load in my collection query.

Comment: @Abdul i dont want to use load in foreach array for every product. I load all details at once.

Comment: don't need to load when you selecting these attribute in query just foreach and echo you required column

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `addAttributeToSelect` in the query and check:

```
$product_ids = array('94', '95', '96');
$collections = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $product_ids));

foreach ($collections as $collection) {
    echo $collection->getName();
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get list of products of a particular products ids  then you need to call product collection and filter the collection by array of ids.

Product Collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

For filter by array of product ids  use function `addIdFilter($productArray)`:

```
$collection->addIdFilter($productArray);
```

Then using loop get each product:

```
foreach ($collection as $eachproduct) {
    echo $eachproduct->getName() . '-' . $eachproduct->getId() . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I am only able to get name and price using this. I want also bar code and description also.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$filters = array(
    'type_id',
    'category_ids',
    'website_ids',
    'name',
    'description',
    'short_description',
    'sku',
    'weight',
    'status',
    'url_key',
    'url_path',
    'visibility',
    'has_options',
    'gift_message_available',
    'price',
    'special_price',
    'special_from_date',
    'special_to_date',
    'tax_class_id',
    'tier_price',
    'meta_title',
    'meta_keyword',
    'meta_description',
    'custom_design',
    'custom_layout_update',
    'options_container',
    'image_label',
    'small_image_label',
    'thumbnail_label',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'barcode'
);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productArray));

foreach ($filters as $field) {
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect($field);
}

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getSku();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

// select all attributes
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

// using IN statement,
// i.e. selecting only those items whose ID fall in the given array
$productArray = ['1', '15', '25', '35', '42'];
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('id', ['in' => $productArray]);

foreach ($collection as $eachproduct) {
    $product = $eachproduct->load($eachproduct->getId());
    $product->getDescription();
}
```